# C# to vb.net conversion

Tags: vb.net

I did a C# to VB.net conversion, all went through except 1 thing.

Getting error "End of Statement expected"

**Code**

```
Dim query = From line In allLines Let data = line.Split(","C)New With { _
        Key .number = data(0), _
        Key .ip = data(1) _
    }
```

I am not sure what about the above code it does not like.

**Original C# code**

```
var query = from line in allLines
                        let data = line.Split(',')
                        select new
                        {
                            number = data[0],
                            ip = data[1],
                        };
```

Comment: At least spend a few moments trying to figure it out yourself. At the very least you should have caught this: `allLinesLet` instead of `allLines` and `let`

Comment: @rob this is the first time I have done this type of code, including allLines Let - So not really sure what I am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VB code is missing the keyword `Select`. The equivalent of your C# code should be

```
Dim query = From line In allLines
    Let data = line.Split(","c)
    Select New With {Key .number = data(0), Key .ip = data(1)}
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks alot!